# Trouble trying to scrape price information from newegg in Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, price

I have tried using beautifulsoup to get price information on newegg with no luck.
I tried using the below code and I am trying to get it to return the price of the laptop which is 1268.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/p/1XV-000E-00331?Description=MUHN2LL%2fA&cm_re=MUHN2LL%2fA-_-1XV-000E-00331-_-Product')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'lxml')
price = soup.select_one('[itemprop=price]')['content']
print(price)
```

Can someone help me return 1268?

Comment: please [edit] your question. paste your code as `code` instead of `image`

Answer (score 0):

Your desired target is loaded with `JavaScript`, Therefor `bs4` and `requests` modules will not be able to render the `JS`.

But here's a solution.

All product pages include a stable string which is:

```
Compare offers from more sellers as low as $1,268.90 plus shipping
```

So we will `regex` that and you can apply that within any other page as well.

```py
import requests
import re

params = {
    "Description": "MUHN2LL/A",
    "cm_re": "MUHN2LL/A-_-1XV-000E-00331-_-Product"
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    match = re.search(r'low as.+\$(.+\d)', r.text).group(1)
    print(match)


main("https://www.newegg.com/p/1XV-000E-00331")
```

Output:

```
1,268.90
```

There's other ugly idea where you can parse the `JSONP` encoded:

something like the following:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

params1 = {
    "Description": "MUHN2LL/A",
    "cm_re": "MUHN2LL/A-_-1XV-000E-00331-_-Product"
}

params2 = {
    "FirstCall": "true",
    "PageNum": "1",
    "TabType": "0",
    "FilterBy": "",
    "SortBy": "0",
    "action": "Biz.Product.MoreBuyingOptions.JsonpCallBack"
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url, params=params1)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        params2['ParentItem'] = soup.find(
            "input", id="mboParentItemNumber").get("value")
        params2['MappingId'] = soup.find(
            "input", id="mboMappingId").get("value")
        r = req.get(
            "https://www.newegg.com/Common/Ajax/LoadMoreBuyingOption.aspx", params=params2)
        match = [item.group(1, 2) for item in re.finditer(
            r'price-current-label.+?\>(\d.+?)<.+?p>(.+?)<', r.text)][-1]
        print(match)


main("https://www.newegg.com/p/1XV-000E-00331")
```

Output:

```
('1,268', '.90')
```

Comment: does not work for all pages, not every page has a compare offer display.

Comment: @adammazdarx7 I found a way, will update my answer shortly.